# XML file download using Javascript Not working in IE

Tags: javascript, xml, download

Am trying to create XML file content and download it. For that I wrote code like this,

```
/* Preparing XML Data*/
var XML=new XMLWriter();
    XML.BeginNode("Root Node");
    XML.Attrib("ADIB", "Attribute");   
    XML.Node("Fullname", "Anil");
    XML.Node("D.O.B", "31/12/2015");
    XML.EndNode();
    XML.Close();

/* Downloading as XML file*/    
var data = XML.ToString().replace(/</g,"\n<");              
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href= 'data:application/xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
a.target = '_blank';
a.download = 'New.xml';
a.click();
```

It is working in chrome but not in IE. Can you please help me.

Comment: IE doesn't support the download attribute of <a> tags, although I'm not sure if that is what's wrong.

Comment: Is there any way to download XML file using javascript, which works in IE 7+

Answer (score 0):

It's because of differences with support of data URLS in common browsers. You can check compatibility here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri . And as far as i know, IE has very limited (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

$("a").click(function(e){

```
var xml = $("textarea").text();

if(window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveBlob){

    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.msSaveBlob( new Blob([xml], {type:'application/xml'}), "myfile.xml" )

} 
else 
{
    $(this).attr("href", "data:application/xml," + encodeURIComponent(xml));      
} });
```